# web scraping to get the required output format

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

i am trying to scrap azure sites to get the instance prices but got stuck with with the required output format can any one help me in getting the output..

here is the sample source page

```
<section class="section section-size3"> <div class="row column"> <h2>Virtual machines categories</h2> </div> <div class="row row-size2 column"> <a class="toggler toggler-pricing" data-event="pricingdetails-clicked-accordion" href="#"> <h3 class="heading">General Purpose</h3> <p class="sd-truncateText">Balanced CPU to memory ratio. Ideal for testing and development, small to medium databases and low to medium traffic web servers.</p> </a> <div class="toggled"> <div class="row row-size3 column"> <h3>A0-4 – Basic <a class="arrowLink text-heading5" href="/en-in/pricing/details/virtual-machines/series/#a-series">More information</a></h3> <p>A Basic is an economical option for development workloads, test servers, build servers, code repositories, low-traffic websites and web applications, micro services, early product experiments and small databases.</p> <table class="table-width-even"> <thead> <tr> <th>Instance</th> <th>Cores</th> <th>RAM</th> <th>Disk sizes</th> <th>Price</th> </tr> </thead> <tbody> <tr> <td> A0 </td> <td>1</td> <td>0.75 GB</td> <td><strong>20</strong> GB</td> <td> <span class="price-data " data-amount='{"regional":{"us-east":0.018,"us-west":0.018,"us-north-central":0.018,"us-south-central":0.018,"europe-north":0.018,"europe-west":0.018,"asia-pacific-southeast":0.018,"asia-pacific-east":0.018,"japan-east":0.022,"japan-west":0.019,"brazil-south":0.022,"us-east-2":0.018,"us-central":0.018,"usgov-virginia":0.017,"usgov-iowa":0.017,"australia-east":0.024,"australia-southeast":0.024,"central-india":0.018,"south-india":0.016,"canada-east":0.02,"canada-central":0.022,"germany-central":0.021,"germany-northeast":0.021,"united-kingdom-west":0.02,"united-kingdom-south":0.02,"us-west-2":0.018,"us-west-central":0.018}}' data-hour-format="{0}/hr" data-month-format="{0}/mo" data-region-unavailable="N/A">$0.018</span> </td> </tr> <tr> <td> A1 </td> <td>1</td> <td>1.75 GB</td> <td><strong>40</strong> GB</td> <td> <span class="price-data " data-amount='{"regional":{"us-east":0.035,"us-west":0.034,"us-north-central":0.038,"us-south-central":0.035,"europe-north":0.028,"europe-west":0.027,"asia-pacific-southeast":0.037,"asia-pacific-east":0.046,"japan-east":0.04,"japan-west":0.044,"brazil-south":0.054,"us-east-2":0.024,"us-central":0.038,"usgov-virginia":0.04,"usgov-iowa":0.04,"australia-east":0.04,"australia-southeast":0.046,"central-india":0.038,"south-india":0.042,"canada-east":0.038,"canada-central":0.042,"germany-central":0.0322,"germany-northeast":0.0322,"united-kingdom-west":0.056,"united-kingdom-south":0.056,"us-west-2":0.024,"us-west-central":0.035}}' data-hour-format="{0}/hr" data-month-format="{0}/mo" data-region-unavailable="N/A">$0.044</span> </td> </tr> <tr> <td> A2 </td> <td>2</td> <td>3.50 GB</td> <td><strong>60</strong> GB</td> <td> <span class="price-data " data-amount='{"regional":{"us-east":0.079,"us-west":0.081,"us-north-central":0.085,"us-south-central":0.079,"europe-north":0.075,"europe-west":0.078,"asia-pacific-southeast":0.095,"asia-pacific-east":0.104,"japan-east":0.109,"japan-west":0.099,"brazil-south":0.112,"us-east-2":0.068,"us-central":0.085,"usgov-virginia":0.08,"usgov-iowa":0.08,"australia-east":0.098,"australia-southeast":0.104,"central-india":0.096,"south-india":0.094,"canada-east":0.087,"canada-central":0.095,"germany-central":0.0863,"germany-northeast":0.0863,"united-kingdom-west":0.112,"united-kingdom-south":0.112,"us-west-2":0.068,"us-west-central":0.079}}' data-hour-format="{0}/hr" data-month-format="{0}/mo" data-region-unavailable="N/A">$0.088</span> </td> </tr> <tr> <td> A3 </td> <td>4</td> <td>7.00 GB</td> <td><strong>120</strong> GB</td> <td> <span class="price-data " data-amount='{"regional":{"us-east":0.176,"us-west":0.188,"us-north-central":0.188,"us-south-central":0.176,"europe-north":0.188,"europe-west":0.204,"asia-pacific-southeast":0.232,"asia-pacific-east":0.232,"japan-east":0.276,"japan-west":0.2196,"brazil-south":0.232,"us-east-2":0.176,"us-central":0.188,"usgov-virginia":0.16,"usgov-iowa":0.16,"australia-east":0.232,"australia-southeast":0.232,"central-india":0.232,"south-india":0.209,"canada-east":0.194,"canada-central":0.211,"germany-central":0.216,"germany-northeast":0.216,"united-kingdom-west":0.224,"united-kingdom-south":0.224,"us-west-2":0.176,"us-west-central":0.176}}' data-hour-format="{0}/hr" data-month-format="{0}/mo" data-region-unavailable="N/A">$0.176</span> </td> </tr> <tr> <td> A4 </td> <td>8</td> <td>14.00 GB</td> <td><strong>240</strong> GB</td> <td> <span class="price-data " data-amount='{"regional":{"us-east":0.352,"us-west":0.376,"us-north-central":0.376,"us-south-central":0.352,"europe-north":0.376,"europe-west":0.408,"asia-pacific-southeast":0.464,"asia-pacific-east":0.464,"japan-east":0.552,"japan-west":0.4392,"brazil-south":0.464,"us-east-2":0.352,"us-central":0.376,"usgov-virginia":0.32,"usgov-iowa":0.32,"australia-east":0.464,"australia-southeast":0.464,"central-india":0.464,"south-india":0.418,"canada-east":0.387,"canada-central":0.422,"germany-central":0.432,"germany-northeast":0.432,"united-kingdom-west":0.449,"united-kingdom-south":0.449,"us-west-2":0.352,"us-west-central":0.352}}'

</div> <div class="row row-size3 column"> <h3>Av2 Standard <a class="arrowLink text-heading5" href="/en-in/pricing/details/virtual-machines/series/#a-series">More information</a></h3> <p>Av2 Standard is the latest generation of A series VMs with similar CPU performance and faster disk. These VMs are suitable for development workloads, build servers, code repositories, low-traffic websites and web applications, micro services, early product experiments and small databases. Like the prior A Standard generation, Av2 VMs will include load balancing and auto-scaling at no additional charge.</p> <table class="table-width-even"> <thead> <tr> <th>Instance</th> <th>Cores</th> <th>RAM</th> <th>Disk sizes</th> <th>Price</th> </tr> </thead> <tbody> <tr> <td> A1 v2 </td> <td>1</td> <td>2.00 GB</td> <td><strong>10</strong> GB</td> <td> <span class="price-data " data-amount='{"regional":{"us-east":0.043,"us-west":0.043,"us-north-central":0.043,"us-south-central":0.043,"europe-north":0.041,"europe-west":0.041,"asia-pacific-southeast":0.045,"asia-pacific-east":0.05,"japan-east":0.054,"japan-west":0.054,"brazil-south":0.061,"us-east-2":0.043,"us-central":0.043,"usgov-virginia":0.048,"usgov-iowa":0.048,"australia-east":0.5,"australia-southeast":0.05,"central-india":0.047,"south-india":0.047,"canada-east":0.043,"canada-central":0.047,"germany-central":0.055,"germany-northeast":0.055,"united-kingdom-west":0.05,"united-kingdom-south":0.05,"us-west-2":0.036,"us-west-central":0.04}}' data-hour-format="{0}/hr" data-month-format="{0}/mo" data-region-unavailable="N/A">$0.043</span> </td> </tr> <tr> <td> A2 v2 </td> <td>2</td> <td>4.00 GB</td> <td><strong>20</strong> GB</td> <td> <span class="price-data " data-amount='{"regional":{"us-east":0.091,"us-west":0.091,"us-north-central":0.091,"us-south-central":0.091,"europe-north":0.087,"europe-west":0.087,"asia-pacific-southeast":0.095,"asia-pacific-east":0.106,"japan-east":0.113,"japan-west":0.113,"brazil-south":0.129,"us-east-2":0.091,"us-central":0.091,"usgov-virginia":0.097,"usgov-iowa":0.097,"australia-east":0.106,"australia-southeast":0.106,"central-india":0.098,"south-india":0.098,"canada-east":0.091,"canada-central":0.098,"germany-central":0.109,"germany-northeast":0.109,"united-kingdom-west":0.106,"united-kingdom-south":0.106,"us-west-2":0.076,"us-west-central":0.083}}' data-hour-format="{0}/hr" data-month-format="{0}/mo" data-region-unavailable="N/A">$0.091</span> </td> </tr> <tr> <td> A4 v2 </td> <td>4</td> <td>8.00 GB</td> <td><strong>40</strong> GB</td> <td> <span class="price-data " data-amount='{"regional":{"us-east":0.191,"us-west":0.191,"us-north-central":0.191,"us-south-central":0.191,"europe-north":0.183,"europe-west":0.183,"asia-pacific-southeast":0.198,"asia-pacific-east":0.222,"japan-east":0.238,"japan-west":0.238,"brazil-south":0.27,"us-east-2":0.191,"us-central":0.191,"usgov-virginia":0.194,"usgov-iowa":0.194,"australia-east":0.222,"australia-southeast":0.222,"central-india":0.206,"south-india":0.206,"canada-east":0.191,"canada-central":0.206,"germany-central":0.218,"germany-northeast":0.218,"united-kingdom-west":0.222,"united-kingdom-south":0.222,"us-west-2":0.159,"us-west-central":0.175}}' data-hour-format="{0}/hr" data-month-format="{0}/mo" data-region-unavailable="N/A">$0.191</span> </td> </tr> <tr> <td> A8 v2 </td> <td>8</td> <td>16.00 GB</td> <td><strong>80</strong> GB</td> <td> <span class="price-data " data-amount='{"regional":{"us-east":0.6,"us-west":0.4,"us-north-central":0.4,"us-south-central":0.4,"europe-north":0.383,"europe-west":0.383,"asia-pacific-southeast":0.417,"asia-pacific-east":0.467,"japan-east":0.5,"japan-west":0.5,"brazil-south":0.567,"us-east-2":0.4,"us-central":0.4,"usgov-virginia":0.387,"usgov-iowa":0.387,"australia-east":0.467,"australia-southeast":0.467,"central-india":0.433,"south-india":0.433,"canada-east":0.4,"canada-central":0.433,"germany-central":0.437,"germany-northeast":0.437,"united-kingdom-west":0.467,"united-kingdom-south":0.467,"us-west-2":0.333,"us-west-central":0.367}}' data-hour-format="{0}/hr" data-month-format="{0}/mo" data-region-unavailable="N/A">$0.4</span> </td> </tr> <tr> <td> A2m v2 </td> <td>2</td> <td>16.00 GB</td> <td><strong>20</strong> GB</td> <td> <span class="price-data " data-amount='{"regional":{"us-east":0.119,"us-west":0.149,"us-north-central":0.129,"us-south-central":0.124,"europe-north":0.139,"europe-west":0.124,"asia-pacific-southeast":0.134,"asia-pacific-east":0.178,"japan-east":0.153,"japan-west":0.178,"brazil-south":0.208,"us-east-2":0.119,"us-central":0.129,"usgov-virginia":0.176,"usgov-iowa":0.176,"australia-east":0.149,"australia-southeast":0.178,"central-india":0.158,"south-india":0.144,"canada-east":0.129,"canada-central":0.168,"germany-central":0.251,"germany-northeast":0.251,"united-kingdom-west":0.158,"united-kingdom-south":0.178,"us-west-2":0.099,"us-west-central":0.119}}' data-hour-format="{0}/hr" data-month-format="{0}/mo" data-region-unavailable="N/A">$0.149</span> </td> </tr> <tr> <td> A4m v2 </td> <td>4</td> <td>32.00 GB</td> <td><strong>40</strong> GB</td> <td> <span class="price-data " data-amount='{"regional":{"us-east":0.238,"us-west":0.297,"us-north-central":0.27,"us-south-central":0.248,"europe-north":0.291,"europe-west":0.26,"asia-pacific-southeast":0.281,"asia-pacific-east":0.374,"japan-east":0.322,"japan-west":0.374,"brazil-south":0.437,"us-east-2":0.249,"us-central":0.27,"usgov-virginia":0.353,"usgov-iowa":0.353,"australia-east":0.312,"australia-southeast":0.374,"central-india":0.333,"south-india":0.301,"canada-east":0.27,"canada-central":0.353,"germany-central":0.502,"germany-northeast":0.502,"united-kingdom-west":0.333,"united-kingdom-south":0.374,"us-west-2":0.208,"us-west-central":0.249}}' data-hour-format="{0}/hr" data-month-format="{0}/mo" data-region-unavailable="N/A">$0.297</span> </td> </tr> <tr> <td> A8m v2 </td> <td>8</td> <td>64.00 GB</td> <td><strong>80</strong> GB</td> <td> <span class="price-data " data-amount='{"regional":{"us-east":0.475,"us-west":0.594,"us-north-central":0.568,"us-south-central":0.495,"europe-north":0.611,"europe-west":0.546,"asia-pacific-southeast":0.589,"asia-pacific-east":0.786,"japan-east":0.677,"japan-west":0.786,"brazil-south":0.917,"us-east-2":0.524,"us-central":0.568,"usgov-virginia":0.704,"usgov-iowa":0.704,"australia-east":0.655,"australia-southeast":0.786,"central-india":0.699,"south-india":0.633,"canada-east":0.568,"canada-central":0.742,"germany-central":1.004,"germany-northeast":1.004,"united-kingdom-west":0.699,"united-kingdom-south":0.786,"us-west-2":0.437,"us-west-central":0.524}}' data-hour-format="{0}/hr" data-month-format="{0}/mo" data-region-unavailable="N/A">$0.594</span> </td> </tr> </tbody> </table>
```

how can i get below output ...

General Purpose A0 us-east 0.018 General Purpose A0 us-west 0.018......... ...............................so on............................ General Purpose A1 us-east 0.018........ ...............................so on..................... Av2 Standard A0 us-west 0.19..................... ............................................................... ..........and so on...................................

Comment: which python module you use on scrapping web page? BeautifulSoup or Selenium?

Comment: Hi i am using beautifulsoup on python3

Comment: hope you can give me the link, how can i see such page without css?

Comment: Sure here is the link to see the source page https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/virtual-machines/linux/